# Google Optimize test with universal Analytics

Tags: optimization, google-analytics, google-optimize

I'm using Google Optimize with Analytics (UA).
I've made a couple of simple tests with succes but now I'm a little clueless how make to following test:
On a category-page we have an overview of products. The case is that I would like to know if the click-throughs to a product-detail are the same if I remove the button... (image & title are still clickable).
If anyone can put me in the right direction how to test this, it would be highly appreciated! :)
BTW: it must be a/b test, not a multi-variation...

Answer (score 0):

first in your variant code you can remove these buttons (if you are developer is easy with JS in Global JS).
Second you have to check if all links in the card are measured, when title, image or button are clicked must be send an event to Google Analytics.

Third, you have to use this event as primary goal, you can create a custom goal with its action, category and label.